# Probability to reach a space

Tags: probability, dice

**Toss two dice, A starts from $1$, At each turn moves forward with number of steps equal to the sum of numbers on the two dice that are face up. What is the probability that A reaches $440$?**

I thought that the expectation of every step is $7$, then A can reach $435$ with $62$ steps, and the last step is $5$. Therefore, the answer is the probability of two dice sum when sum is $5$, which is $\frac{4}{36}$.

I'm not sure whether the answer is correct or not, need some help, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To see that your method is not correct, change $440$ to $9$. If you apply your reasoning, you would end up with a probability of zero, which is clearly incorrect.

For each integer $n$, let $p(n)$ be the probability that a sum of $n$ can be achieved in some number of steps.

Then $p$ satisfies the recursion
\begin{align*}
p(n)
=
&
\frac{1}{36}p(n-2)
+
\frac{2}{36}p(n-3)
+
\frac{3}{36}p(n-4)
+
\frac{4}{36}p(n-5)
\\[4pt]
&
+
\frac{5}{36}p(n-6)
+
\frac{6}{36}p(n-7)
+
\frac{5}{36}p(n-8)
+
\frac{4}{36}p(n-9)
\\[4pt]
&
+
\frac{3}{36}p(n-10)
+
\frac{2}{36}p(n-11)
+
\frac{1}{36}p(n-12)
\end{align*}
for all $n > 0$, together with the initial conditions $p(0)=1$ and $p(n)=0$ for all $n < 0$.

Here are the values of $p(n)$ for $0\le n\le 12$ . . .
\begin{array}{c|c}
n&p(n)\\
\hline
0&1\\
\hline
1&0\\
\hline
2&{\large{\frac{1}{36}}}\approx .02777777778\\
\hline
3&{\large{\frac{1}{18}}}\approx .05555555556\\
\hline
4&{\large{\frac{109}{1296}}}\approx  .08410493827\\
\hline
5&{\large{\frac{37}{324}}}\approx .1141975309\\
\hline
6&{\large{\frac{6841}{46656}}}\approx .1466263717\\
\hline
7&{\large{\frac{1417}{7776}}}\approx .1822273663\\
\hline
8&{\large{\frac{279397}{1679616}}}\approx .1663457600\\
\hline
9&{\large{\frac{32653}{209952}}}\approx .1555260250\\
\hline
10&{\large{\frac{8935921}{60466176}}}\approx .1477837957\\
\hline
11&{\large{\frac{4271189}{30233088}}}\approx .1412753140\\
\hline
12&{\large{\frac{292122973}{2176782336}}}\approx .1341994412\\
\hline
\end{array}
Given that $A$ starts at position $1$, the probability that $A$ reaches position $440$ is equal to $p(439)$. Applying the recursion using a CAS such as Maple or Mathematica, $p(439)$ evaluates to a rational number with huge numerator and denominator, but it is approximately $1/7$.

Comment: The same idea, but with $p(n,k)$ -- reaching $n$ with $k$ throws, and suming up only $p(n,2m)$ using matrix powers for the recursion.